# How can i store curl result in a variable?

Tags: bash, curl, cookies, csrf

I am trying to store two variables **user_token** and **PHPSESSID** using the following commands:

```
CSRF_token=$(curl -l "http://127.0.0.1/DVWA-master/login.php" | awk '/user_token/ {print $4}/')
```

```
PHPSESSID=$(curl -c "http://127.0.0.1/DVWA-master/login.php" | awk '/PHPSESSID/ {print $7}/')
```

My problem is that when I print those 2 varaibles they always return the same value, but if i execute those two previous commands, those values change (that is how it has to work).

Is there anything that I am doing wrong or it is just that variables can't update its value.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
CURL_OUT=$(curl -l "http://127.0.0.1/DVWA-master/login.php")
CSRF_token=$(echo "${CURL_OUT}" | awk '/user_token/ {print $4}/')
PHPSESSID=$(echo "${CURL_OUT}" | awk '/PHPSESSID/ {print $7}/')
```

Comment: By doing that the variables keep returning the same value. It should update everytime you call it. Instead it returns always the same string. I'll keep trying things and if I get the solution I'll post it. Thank you.